# SQL error:Why test table doesn't exist?

Tags: mysql, error-handling

I am doing SQL practice on Leetcode website and a common error I come across is

```
'test table xxx doesn't exist'
```

I saw someone was mentioning that I don't have permission to these tables, but I don't understand why. Under what circumstances do I loss permission to the test tables? For example, what specific error in the code can cause this problem? Thanks!

Addition: For example, I was trying to solve the 184. Department Highest Salary leetcode problem with the following code:

```
select d.Name as "Department", e.Name as "Employee", Salary
from Empolyee e
join Department d
on d.Id = e.DepartmentId
where (e.DepartmentId , Salary) in (select DepartmentId, max(Salary)
                                  from Employee
                                  group by DepartmentId)
```

The error I receive is:

```
Table 'test.empolyee' doesn't exist
```

However, the following code (which is very similar to my above code) is correct! Anyone know why? Thanks!

```
SELECT Department.name AS 'Department',
       Employee.name AS 'Employee',
       Salary
FROM Employee
JOIN Department 
ON Employee.DepartmentId = Department.Id
WHERE (Employee.DepartmentId , Salary) IN (SELECT DepartmentId, MAX(Salary)
                                          FROM Employee
                                          GROUP BY DepartmentId)
```

Comment: Can you share the query you were trying to execute, your question is very vague.

Comment: @Tommassiov I added more details to the question. Thanks!

Comment: Empolyee is spelt wrong ?

Comment: aha, yes! I've been stupid....

Comment: It's funny because I had the same error on the exact same leetcode problem.  I also had the same solution oddly enough.